# NodeJS memory footprint and OOM

Tags: node.js, microservices

I am running a small nodejs application and started getting OOM errors for one of the actions:

> ## Fatal error in , line 0
>
> ## API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
>
> ## FailureMessage Object: 0x7f0e269659b0

I took memory dumps and they have around 26MBs in size, both prior and after the error is printed to the console. Also my process memory usage (Ubuntu is the host) is not that high:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                              
21069 ashley    20   0 1185368  39584  24616 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.70 node
```

If I interpret this output correctly, node process is using less than 40MBs of resident memory. Basically there is no memory leak or anything similar. According to google, default memory of node process on Ubuntu is 1.7GBs. Now, I am puzzled why my process is failing, why node process takes so much memory. Based on what I found most people just increase memory available to node using --max-old-space-size flag. If that's the solution, I am really puzzled why node is so memory hungry, the similar app written in java using springboot most likely is going to perform excellent with just 256-512MBs of memory.

And, if nodejs VM instances need at least 2-3GBs of memory, this makes node microservices significantly more expensive than java ones in terms of cloud costs.

I am still hoping that there is a gap in my NodeJS knowledge and my simple node app can fit into VM with just 512MB-1GB micro VM.

I will appreciate any thoughts, links, suggestions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by passing incorrect value (object instead of primitive to Sequelize) which caused memory leak. The problem was detected by looking at memory dump.